# This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I'm writing a test code with Jest for a custom hook in my web application.

It uses Recoil for state management, but the error message appears when I run `npm run test`.

This is the error message.
[image]

It seems that the problem is somewhere in the current-user.js file at this code block:
Code index.jsx

```
function Account({ onSubmit = handleSubmit, ...props }) {
    const profile = useRecoilValue(userProfile);
    const [isDoneProfil, setIsDoneProfil] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-full bg-[#F5F5F5]">

            <main className="h-screen relative">
                <div className='h-screen flex bg-gray-bg my-15 static'>
                    <div className='w-full mt-10 m-auto bg-white rounded-lg border border-primaryBorder shadow-default md:w-4/12'>
                        <div>

                            <div className='space-y-4 bg-white rounded-lg w-full sm:h-96 p-0 overflow-y-scroll scrollbar mb-5 tems-center px-4 mr-2"'>
                                <div className="divide-y ">
                                    <div className="p-3">
                                        <form
                                            id="add-form"
                                            onSubmit={onSubmit}
                                            aria-label="Edit a Account"
                                            className="space-y-3 text-right"
                                            name="Account"
                                            action=""
                                        >

                                            <div>
                                                <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-left text-slate-500" htmlFor="fullname">Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" className="bg-gray-50 border text-sm text-gray-700 rounded-lg text-slate-500 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-3.5" defaultValue={profile?.fullname} />
                                            </div>

                                            <div>
                                                <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-left text-slate-500" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="email" className="bg-gray-50 border text-sm text-gray-700 rounded-lg text-slate-500 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-3.5" defaultValue={profile?.email} />
                                            </div>

                                        </form>

                                        <div className="text-right mt-6">

                                            <button
                                                onClick={() => {
                                                    setIsDoneProfil(true)
                                                }}
                                                type="button"
                                                className="text-white bg-red-600 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-black-200 rounded-lg border text-sm font-medium px-8 py-2.5 focus:z-10 dark:bg-black-700 dark:text-white-300 dark:border-black-500 "
                                                form="add-form"
                                                id="add-form"
                                            >
                                                SAVE
                                            </button>
                                            {isDoneProfil && <Done setIsDone={setIsDoneProfil} />}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div >
    );
};
```

and Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Account from "./index";

describe('Account', () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(() => {
        onSubmit.mockClear();
        render(<Account onSubmit={onSubmit} />);
    });

    it('onSubmit is called when all fields pass validation', async () => {
        user.type(getName(), 'Me');
        user.type(getEmail(), 'viewer@gmail.id');

        clickButtonSimpan();

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                name: 'Me',
                nik: '0000000000000000',
                email: 'viewer@gmail.id',
            });
        });

        expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});


function getName() {
    user.click(screen.getByRole('textbox', {
        name: /name/i
    }));
}

function getEmail() {
    user.click(screen.getByRole('textbox', {
        name: /email/i
    }));
}

function clickButtonSimpan() {
    user.click(screen.getByRole('button', {
        name: /save/i
    }));
}
```

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should try rendering your component inside a `RecoilRoot`.
Are you not able to for any reason?

```js
render(
   <RecoilRoot>
      <Account onSubmit={onSubmit} />
   </RecoilRoot>
);
```